# How to design a database schema for a multi-user To-Do application in Azure?

Tags: c#, database-design, azure, winrt, uwp

I want to create a windows 10 universal to-do app with offline sync capability. So I checked out [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data/) tutorial which helped me to get started on the offline functionality. But I was wondering how should I design my Azure database to get data efficiently and moreover I also should have the ability to store images. So here are my questions:

1. Is it good to put all the users data in one table? Ex: (Content
   Table): ID , FK(UserId), Title, Desc, Created , Edited.
2. Can I use any indexing technique to efficiently query for the user
   data as CRUD operations will be very common since it has a sync
   feature.

If the above is not really a good technique could you please tell me what is the right way to go about it. As I'm not so experienced when it comes to DB designing.

Comment: Are users going to share tasks? A single user querying a hundred task records in a table with a million records is not that much especially if you index on the user id foreign key.

Comment: No users don't share task(For now at least). I'm going to go with the solution given here and get back if any problems or optimizations are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the tables you might want

1. User (User_Id, Name, and so on)
2. Category (Category_Id, Name)
3. Task (Task_Id, Category_FK, User_FK, Name, Date_Due)

[This article](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/indexes-azure-sql-database-v12) will give you some background on indexes in Azure.

If you are going to have heavy hits to the database. It would be better to place the database into a caching system. This would take the load off the database.

Comment: How do you think I can query the results efficiently cause there will be a lot of CURD operations and the tables will contain at least a couple of millions of records and will increase every day by a large amount.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith see my edit